# The higher the gain the more white noise

Tags: recording, noise, noise-reduction

I use the samson c01 condensor mic with the scarlet solo 2nd gen interface, I use logic pro x to record on.

I record vocals in the closet with blankets and everything surrounding so there is no noise but when i increase the gain there is still white noise.

When the gain is low there is not much noise but when you add compression you can hear it, i do noise removal on audacity but when you record guitar and add noise removal it sounds terrible.

Comment: Process of elimination - figure out which part of your gain staging is the noisy bit & minimise it, or swap it out.

Answer (score 1):

When you add compression, you need either quite low-noise equipment to start with (and a Samson C01, even though formally a large-diaphragm condensor, is not in the same ballpark as even a small-diaphragm Røde NT55) or a noise gate.

"Noise removal" makes no sense for recordings intended to be of good quality: that's an emergency measure for bootleg or incidental recordings, usually tailored towards improving speech intelligibility.

So drop the "noise removal" and instead try adding a noise gate and/or limit the amount of compression (in particular its maximum gain) you use.

Answer (score 1):

Every device that uses electricity inherently generates signal noise. Higher quality mics and equipment will have less signal noise.

Also consider how the power is supplied. Power coming from the wall can fluctuate, so running it through a power conditioner will reduce the noise introduced from there.

Like the other answer said, a noise gate or expander can help. I recommend an expander so you can smoothly transition, rather than sharp cuts of the noise.

You can also try EQ filtering at 60hz or 50hz (US, and UK respectively).